# AtomicInteger for limited sequence generation

Tags: java, atomic

How can we use AtomicInteger for limited sequence generation say the sequence number has to be between 1 to 60. Once the sequence reaches 60 it has to start again from 1. I wrote this code though not quite sure wether this is thread safe or not?

```
public int getNextValue()
{
 int v;
 do
 {
   v = val.get();
   if ( v == 60)
   {
    val.set(1);
   }
 }
  while (!val.compareAndSet(v , v + 1));
   return v + 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of Java 8, you can use [`AtomicInteger.updateAndGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#updateAndGet-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-):

```
return val.updateAndGet(n -> (n >= 60) ? 1 : n + 1);
```

---

Another alternative would be to simply do...

```
return val.getAndIncrement() % 60;
```

...unless you're concerned with exceeding the integer max-value (2147483647). If that is a concern, you could have a look at the `getAndIncrement` implementation:

```
public final int getAndIncrement() {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        int next = current + 1;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return current;
    }
}
```

All you need to change is the `int next...` line to something like:

```
int next = (current + 1) % 60;
```

---

Oops. This loops through 0->59. You needed 1->60, so add one to the return-value to get the desired result.

Comment: What a strange implementation. Basically it says "add 1 if it hasn't changed yet, otherwise keep trying". Couldn't that theoretically result in an infinite loop?

Comment: Could this result in an infinite loop? Absolutely. But the odds of this instance being under such tight contention that we loop more than a few dozens of times is astronomically low, and this implementation is willing to burn a few CPU cycles in failed attempts instead of burning even more CPU cycles acquiring a lock.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this in a single line using Java 8.

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

public int getNextValue() {
    return counter.updateAndGet(n -> (n >= 60) ? 1 : n + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you make the method `synchronized` then it will be threadsafe as long as the `val` is nowhere else accessed. The approach is however a bit cumbersome, I'd rewrite it as follows:

```
public synchronized int getNextValue() {
    val.compareAndSet(60, 0); // Set to 0 if current value is 60.
    return val.incrementAndGet();
}
```

This gives 1 until with 60 back **inclusive**. If you actually need 1 until with 59, then replace `60` by `59`.

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason to use AtomicInteger here rather than just a simple synchronized method?

How about something simple like the following:

```
private int val=1;

public synchronized int getNextValue() {
 int v=val;
 val = (val==60) ? 1 : (val+1); 
 return v;
}
```

Comment: p.s. nothing against AtomicIntegers but I think it's always good to make things as simple as possible in the interests of long term maintainability....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking for a Non-blocking algorithm insted of the Blocking algorithm.

Comment: AtomicInteger is much faster than synchronization if there is a lot of contention (up to a factor of 10).

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not thread safe - you shouldn't call `set` inside a cycle:

```
int value, next;
do {
    value = val.get();
    next = (value == 60) ? 1 : (value + 1);
} while (!val.compareAndSet(value, next);
return next;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer, not thread safe. The test and set need to be atomic, unless you make the whole method synchronized. Note the val.get() and the test of v are not atomic. If the thread yields after v = val.get() you'll get two calls with the same sequence number.

Also, if the compareAndSet fails you never change the values, it'll be an infinite loop.

AtomicInteger has a
   getAndIncrement()
call. That will get you a clean value to return.

The rolling is a bit trickier. One solution is to mod the return value. Something like so:

```
int v = val.getAndIncrement();
return (v % 60) + 1;
```

Since each thread has a local copy of v we can safely do some math on it and return the value. There is one sticking point if you get an overflow. Depending on how often you generate a sequence number this may or may not be an issue.

Comment: The frequeny of the generation is quite high, probably every 50 ms.

Comment: At 20 calls per second (a call every 50ms) you'd get a rollover after approximately 3.4 years. Probably not too bad, depending on your app. If that's going to be a problem, a synchronized block is probably the easiest solution. Make sure this code is a real bottleneck before you go crazy optimizing it. I suspect there are lower hanging fruit than a task that runs every 50ms.